# Set active slide in modal click on Swiper slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, swiper.js

Im having a table where it has a a button which opens up a modal window and inside the modal there is a [Swiper](http://idangero.us/swiper/) slider which shows some text/slide

What i need to do is when someone clicks on a button, on the modal it should automatically load the relevant slide on Swiper.

For an example, When i click on SET 1 It should show slide 1, and when i click on SET 2it should load the second slider with the proper pagination selected.

Below is my code

JS

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
    });
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Set 1</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Set 2</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Set 3</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Set 4</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content panel-warning">
        <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         
        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>
           
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
        </div>
        
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/fu8mezk3/7/

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML:

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Set 1</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-slider="0" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Set 2</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-slider="1" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Set 3</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-slider="2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Set 4</td>
  <td><a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-slider="3" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">View</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content panel-warning">
        <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 4</div>

        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
        </div>

      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

JS:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
 var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
        paginationClickable: true,
        spaceBetween: 30,
    });


    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
     swiper.update();
    var $invoker = $(e.relatedTarget);
      swiper.slideTo($invoker.data('slider'));
      swiper.update();
    });

    });
```

this should do the job. !!

Comment: Thanks.... It works... But there is a small issue. First time when i click on a button it shows the first slide after that it works normally. and when i click on the first button it highlights the incorrect pagination bullet. You can check the fiddle over here https://jsfiddle.net/livewirerules/fu8mezk3/9/

Comment: i hv updated the js a little bit. try it...it should be fine now.
btw ur fiddle didnt had the `data-slider`

Comment: Perfect... Thanks alot..one more thing, when i click one button and then click another one it shows the previous one and then moves to the correct one.. eg: when i click on the first button and then clicnk on the 3rd button it shows the first slide and then moves to the 3rd. Is it possible to directly show the 3rd slide without showing the previous one?

Comment: Try changing model event from `shown.bs.modal` to `show.bs.modal`

Comment: Hmm... If we cn disable the slide animation then your desired effect would  be seen  i guess.